# list compression weird behavior

Tags: python

I have question about list comprehension. If I want to output the odd squared numbers and put the condition in the output part (I know how to put condition in the loop part to get the desired result)

```
[num**2 if num % 2==0 for num in range(10)]
```

returned an error code. Why Python doesn't like it?

By adding else, the following returns zeros

```
[num**2 if num % 2==0 else 0 for num in range(10)]
```

so I tried to remove zeros on top of this

```
[num**2 if num % 2==0 else 0 for num in range(10)].remove(0)
```

and python returned empty, why?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. [num**2 if num % 2==0 for num in range(10)] returned an error code. Why Python doesn't like it?

You have the list comprehension syntax backwards. The `for` comes first, then the `if`.

```
[num**2 for num in range(10) if num % 2 == 0]
```

Alternatively, use `range`’s `step` parameter:

```
[num**2 for num in range(0, 10, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension is out of order.

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression
>   followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. -- [Python, Data Structures Documentation, List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Change your first one to:

```
[num**2 for num in range(10) if num % 2 == 0]
```

output:

```
[0, 4, 16, 36, 64]
```